# question about systems of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{3 \times 3}$ such that the linear system $Ax = (1,1,1)^t$ has a solution but the system $Ax = (1,1,0)^t$ does not.

Which of the following options is correct ?

- The system $Ax=(0,0,0)^t$ has a more than $1$ solution;
- The system $Ax=(2 2 1)^t$  has no solutions;
- For all $0\neq C \in \mathbb R^{3 \times 3}$ the system $ACx=(1,1,1)^t$ has a solution
- If $D$ is row equivalent to $A$, the system Dc=91 1 1) has a solution
- $r(A)=2$

What I can understand is that $A$ is not $0$ so $r(A)!=0$. Also because $Ax=(1 1 0)$ has no solution $r(A)<3$, so the first option is not true.

But I'm not sure about the other options

Comment: Please show some of your work and where you are stuck if you want people to give you good feedback

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial